# Can't build the haskell shakespeare library on windows 10. Any ideas?

Tags: windows, cabal, yesod

I'm trying to install Yesod through cabal on my HP computer, but the building process fails when shakespeare library gets the turn. MSYS2+MinGW in the path, the rest actually works. What could be the issue? I have my suspicions that it might be due to the x64 processor I have, but not sure.

Tried installing globally with runhaskell, but same story.

```
C:\Users\Ivan Kretov>cabal install shakespeare
Warning: The install command is a part of the legacy v1 style of cabal 
usage.

Please switch to using either the new project style and the new-install
command or the legacy v1-install alias as new-style projects will become 
the default in the next version of cabal-install. Please file a bug if 
you cannot replicate a working v1- use case with the new-style commands.

For more information, see: https://wiki.haskell.org/Cabal/NewBuild

Resolving dependencies...
Starting     shakespeare-2.0.20
Building     shakespeare-2.0.20
```